# trying to install tendermint for cluster of nodes

Tags: tendermint

I am trying to install tendermint using the guide link:[https://tendermint.com/docs/introduction/quick-start.html#cluster-of-nodes]

I am doing this in 4 different virtual machines installed on virtualbox

all machines are pingable and have different ip address

in spite of this i get error: No addresses to dial nor connected peers. Falling back to seeds module=p2p
 when i run the command

tendermint node --home ./mytestnet/node0 --proxy_app=kvstore --p2p.persistent_peers="ID1@IP1:26656,ID2@IP2:26656,ID3@IP3:26656,ID4@IP4:26656"
tendermint node --home ./mytestnet/node1 --proxy_app=kvstore --p2p.persistent_peers="ID1@IP1:26656,ID2@IP2:26656,ID3@IP3:26656,ID4@IP4:26656"
tendermint node --home ./mytestnet/node2 --proxy_app=kvstore --p2p.persistent_peers="ID1@IP1:26656,ID2@IP2:26656,ID3@IP3:26656,ID4@IP4:26656"
tendermint node --home ./mytestnet/node3 --proxy_app=kvstore --p2p.persistent_peers="ID1@IP1:26656,ID2@IP2:26656,ID3@IP3:26656,ID4@IP4:26656"

I have encountered similar issue when i was trying to set up a bigchaindb server.
is there any other settings to be done on VMs or do we need real ubuntu machines rather than VM

Comment: Are you using the actual IDs and IP addresses when you run the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have met this issue ever. I solved this by closing the shadowsocks vpn. Although they were not the same port, but it did affect. I use virtual box for 2 vms.